# Запуск сервиса в фоновом режиме без уведомления

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, как в приложении запустить сервис в фоновом режиме без  уведомления?

И что  может значить то, что мое уведомление постоянно обновляется, как можно это исправить?

Сейчас использую такой код:

```
private void startForeground() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, 
            NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID) // don't forget create a notification channel first
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Service is running background")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build());
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вроде бы только если сделать приложение системным, договорившись в производителем девайса или с гуглом можно будет не показывать постоянно уведомление на ОС версии больше 8. Возможно, вам оно и не нужно? Какую вы задачу хотите этим решить?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, фоновый сервис мне нужен для будильника, т.е. он каждую минуту проверяет время с записанным мною временем

Comment: Такую задачу надо не через сервис решать. Скорее всего вам тут нужен AlarmManager. Посмотрите доку тут https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms и ещё вот эту статью, например: https://learntodroid.com/how-to-create-a-simple-alarm-clock-app-in-android/

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, возможно ли с помощью Alarm Manager после выключения будильника установить следующий ну другое время, не заходя в приложение?

Comment: Конечно можно .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с [Android версии 8+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) вы не можете запускать никакие фоновые задачи без явного уведомления пользователя.

Для того, чтоб вам запускать какие-то запланированные задачи Google предоставляет [Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

[Здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/562-urok-29-workmanager-vvedenie.html) есть урок как им пользоваться.